# Rendering raw frames

Tags: windows, graphics

I want to display some raw bitmaps at 60 times per second. The bitmap is around 40k and is just a matrix of pixels. In Linux I did this by writing directly into the frame buffer. Is there an easy method in Windows to render this kind of stream?

Comment: GDI,OpenGL,DirectX. The easiest is GDI (it supports bitmaps and direct rendering on screen) but there you might hit a speed wall. OpenGL is harder to start with but should be more than fast enough. DirectX should be more or less similar to OpenGL but IMHO the DirectX code is too much complicated and also my experience worse (not working callbacks, very bad latency ...)  so I am not using it unless I am really forced to. But my experience might be biased by earlier versions of DirectX over the years situation might changed ...

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look also on GDI. Meanwhile I found SDL. It is seems that it hides many of the DirectX complexity and has some nice sample projects to start from.

Comment: IIRC SDL is based on OpenGL ...

Comment: And this is good or bad?

Comment: That depends on who is answering ... at least GL is corss-platform so it work on linux too (so SDL might be working in similar manner too) DirectX is only for Windows ...